# View a specific Git commit

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Information about a SHA-1 commit object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610073/get-information-about-a-sha-1-commit-object)

I needed to check when a specific change was added to a file I'm working on, so I used the `git blame` command. From that I obtained the hash of the relevant commit. **Is there a way to see the log notes of just that commit, using the hash?** All the docs talk about how to look at the whole tree.

I realize could just do `git log <filename>`, but there are a lot of commits for the file, and I'm loathe to go through all of them looking for this one. A simple way to view the log notes would be appreciated.

Comment: Voting to re-open so the OTHER question can be closed in favor of this, or they can be more softly linked perhaps..

Answer (score 609, accepted):

```
git show <revhash>
```

Documentation [here](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html).
Or if that doesn't work, try [Google Code's Git Documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20160505053436/http://git-htmldocs.googlecode.com:80/git/git-show.html)

Comment: Your `reflog` can be viewed too - for example, the last commit can be seen with `git show HEAD`. One more back? `git show HEAD~1`.

Comment: Use git show REVISION:/path/to/file to view a particular file only